# How do I pass a Linked List of custom objects between activities in an android application?

Tags: java, android

I need a linked list of custom objects when trying to bundle it I do not see a putObjectLinkedList method is there an easy way of doing this or must implement the Parcable interface in my custom object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LinkedLists are Serializable. Have you tried putSerializable(String key, Serializable value)? Your custom objects will need to implement Serializable as well though.