# Sending ArrayList between 2 fragments on same Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist

I have 2 Fragments and an Activity. 
Fragment 1 has a relative layout with a listview and some buttons etc, 
Fragment 2 has a ListView and a button at the bottom. fragment 2's listview is a listview where you can select multiple items, when an item is selected, it is added to an arraylist (we will call this selected) or removed if deselected, I want to send this arrayList over to Fragment 1, where it can add it to its own listview (as well as its other items if they exist). I have the selected ArrayList stored in Activity.

Activity has the following code

```
public class AddExerciseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;
static ArrayList<Set> sets = new ArrayList<>();

String name, date;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        name = extras.getString("ExerciseName");
        date = extras.getString("date");
    }

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setTitle(name);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}




/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("date", date);
                bundle.putInt("position", position);
                return new FirstFragment();
            case 1:
                return new SecondFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }



    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Track";
            case 1:
                return "History";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Set> getSets() {
    return sets;
}

public void setSets(ArrayList<Set> sets) {
    this.sets = sets;
}
}
```

Here is Fragment 1

```
public class FirstFragment  extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

CardDatabaseAdapter2 mCardDatabaseAdapter2;

TextView workoutName;
EditText weight, reps;
double weightCount;
int repsCount;
ListView list;
Button plus, plus2, minus, minus2, update;
String name, date;
int type, category, count;
Exercise ex;
Card card;
View rootView;
ArrayList<Set> array = new ArrayList<>();
private AddExerciseAdapter mAddExerciseAdapter;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_exercise_view, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        name = extras.getString("ExerciseName");
        type = extras.getInt("ExerciseType");
        category = extras.getInt("ExerciseCategory");
        date = extras.getString("date");
        Log.v("date", date);
    }
    mCardDatabaseAdapter2 = new CardDatabaseAdapter2(getActivity());

    Log.v("created", "item created");

    //mCardDatabaseAdapter2.insert(name, date);
    card = new Card(0, name, date);
    Log.v("name & date", name + "  " + date);

    ex = new Exercise(name, type, category);
    Log.v("Exercise Recieved", ex.toString());
    workoutName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    weight = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textWeight);
    reps = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textRep);
    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rowReps);
    plus = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    minus = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
    plus2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.plus2);
    minus2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.minus2);
    update = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.update);

    weightCount = 0;
    repsCount = 0;
    count = 1;

    array = new ArrayList<>();
    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!weight.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                weightCount = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
                weightCount = weightCount + 2.5;
                weight.setText(String.valueOf(weightCount));
            } else {
                weight.setText(String.valueOf(2.5));
            }
        }
    });

    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(weightCount <= 0.0 || weight.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                weight.setText(String.valueOf(0.0));
            } else {
                weightCount = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
                weightCount = weightCount - 2.5;
                weight.setText(String.valueOf(weightCount));
            }
        }
    });

    plus2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!reps.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                repsCount = Integer.parseInt(reps.getText().toString());
                repsCount = repsCount + 1;
                reps.setText(String.valueOf(repsCount));
            } else {
                reps.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            }
        }
    });

    minus2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(repsCount <= 0 || reps.getText().toString().equals("")){
                reps.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            } else {
                repsCount = Integer.parseInt(reps.getText().toString());
                repsCount = repsCount - 1;
                reps.setText(String.valueOf(repsCount));
            }
        }
    });

    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(weight.getText().toString().equals("") || weight.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(0.0))) {
                weight.setText(String.valueOf(0.0));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You need to enter a weight!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(reps.getText().toString().equals("")|| reps.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(0))) {
                reps.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You need to have at least 1 rep!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                double temp2 = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
                int temp3 = Integer.parseInt(reps.getText().toString());
                Set s = new Set(name, temp2, temp3, date);
                array.add(s);
                //mCardDatabaseAdapter2.insert2(mCardDatabaseAdapter2.highestID(), name, s.getWeight(), s.getReps(), date);
                //Log.v("inserted data", "id " + mCardDatabaseAdapter2.highestID() + " name " + name + " weight " + s.getWeight() + " reps " + s.getReps() + " date " + date);
                //Log.v("id", mCardDatabaseAdapter2.highestID() + "");
                mAddExerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                count++;
            }
        }
    });
    mAddExerciseAdapter = new AddExerciseAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row2, array);
    list.setAdapter(mAddExerciseAdapter);

    mAddExerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_exercise, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_done) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainMenuActivity.class);
        if(!array.isEmpty()) {
            mCardDatabaseAdapter2.insert(name, date);
            for (Set s : array) {
                mCardDatabaseAdapter2.insert2(mCardDatabaseAdapter2.highestID(), name, s.getWeight(), s.getReps(), date);
            }
            mCardDatabaseAdapter2.resetID();
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ArrayList<Set> s = ((AddExerciseActivity)getActivity()).getSets();
    if(!s.isEmpty()) {
        for(Set t : s) {
            array.add(t);
            mAddExerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
}
```

and here is Fragment 2

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

CardDatabaseAdapter2 mCardDatabaseAdapter;
ExerciseHistoryAdapter mExerciseHistoryAdapter;
AddExerciseActivity mAddExerciseActivity;
ArrayList<Set> sets = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Set> selected = new ArrayList<>();
String name;
ListView lv;
Card c;
int x;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_history, container, false);
    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        name = extras.getString("ExerciseName");
    }
    mAddExerciseActivity = new AddExerciseActivity();
    mCardDatabaseAdapter = new CardDatabaseAdapter2(getActivity());
    sets = mCardDatabaseAdapter.getAllSetsWithName(name);
    Log.v("array", sets.toString());

    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.history_list);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (!selected.contains(sets.get(position))) {
                lv.setItemChecked(position, true);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 152, 0));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                selected.add(sets.get(position));
            } else {
                lv.setItemChecked(position, false);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(221, 221, 221));
                selected.remove(sets.get(position));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item Unselected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });



    Button add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((AddExerciseActivity)getActivity()).setSets(selected);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "items have been added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mExerciseHistoryAdapter= new ExerciseHistoryAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.history_listview_item, sets, lv);
    lv.setAdapter(mExerciseHistoryAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

EDIT: my attempt is in there, where I get/set the arrayList. but it doesnt work as the fragment is already created.

EDIT 2:

```
04-23 20:18:48.034      598-598/com.company.joeliomason.projectmeE/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exceptiondispatching input event.
04-23 20:18:48.034      598-598/com.company.joeliomason.projectme
E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: 
handleReceiveCallback
04-23 20:18:48.034      598-598/com.company.joeliomason.projectme 
E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already 
active
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setArguments(Fragment.java:549)
        at com.company.joeliomason.projectme.Views.FirstFragment.setArguments(FirstFragment.java:200)
        at com.company.joeliomason.projectme.Views.AddExerciseActivity.onTabSelected(AddExerciseActivity.java:94)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.selectTab(WindowDecorActionBar.java:640)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(WindowDecorActionBar.java:414)
        at com.company.joeliomason.projectme.Views.AddExerciseActivity$1.onPageSelected(AddExerciseActivity.java:68)
```

Comment: Why not just keep the list in your activity? :P

Comment: have a look at it [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass a Linked List of custom objects between activities in an android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419997/how-do-i-pass-a-linked-list-of-custom-objects-between-activities-in-an-android-a)

Comment: @bharat I tried implementing that but it didnt work

Comment: and @BojanKseneman what do you mean? which one??

Comment: Are both fragments in the same activity? If so, you should keep the list in the activity and implement communication between your fragment and activity. There are millions of samples on how to do this

Comment: Is it the `sets` ArrayList that you want to pass into Fragment1?  Is `Set` serializable?

Comment: @Joeliomason Looks like you accidentally posted a comment as an answer, you should delete that.  It looks like you are already getting it though `getSets()`, is that not working?

Comment: whoops! was using the android app :P and no its not, because the Fragment 1 has already been created, so its not actually going to get called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, but I haven't tested it.
It looks like you could pass a `Bundle` using a new method call in your `onTabSelected()` method.

Create a reference to `FirstFragment` as an instance variable in `AddExerciseActivity`:

```
ViewPager mViewPager;
static ArrayList<Set> sets = new ArrayList<>();
FirstFragment fragmentFirst; //added
```

Set it in your `SectionsPagerAdapter`:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("date", date);
                bundle.putInt("position", position);
                fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment(); //modified
                return fragmentFirst; //added
            case 1:
                return new SecondFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then, add , add `sets` to a `Bundle`, and pass it into `FirstFragment` in `onTabSelected`:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    if (fragmentFirst != null){
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putSerializable("sets", sets);
       //fragmentFirst.setArguments(bundle); //not working
       fragmentFirst.updateArguments(bundle); //try this
    }

}
```

Edit:  Add a new public method in `FragmentFirst`:

```
public void updateArguments(Bundle args) { 
     ArrayList<Set> x = new ArrayList<>(); 
     x = (ArrayList<Set>) args.getSerializable("sets"); 
     for(Set p: x) { 
        array.add(p); 
     } 
     mAddExerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
   }
```

Comment: array = args.getSerializable("sets");             //required java.lang.array, found java.io.serializable

Comment: I have a class called Card which is serializable, inside has an ArrayList of "Set", it might be easier to pass that over

Comment: Try `array = (ArrayList<Set>) args.getSerializable("sets")` and see if that works.

Comment: it produced an error, ill update my question with what its producing

Comment: worked perfectly, although I changed updateArguments a bit because it wasnt doing anything,     public void updateArguments(Bundle args) {

        ArrayList<Set> x = new ArrayList<>();
        x = (ArrayList<Set>) args.getSerializable("sets");
        for(Set p: x) {
            array.add(p);
        }
        mAddExerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: im just wondering, how do I show my FirstFragment after pressing the button in SecondFragment??

Comment: @Joeliomason Great!  Glad it's working for you now!  I'll take a look at the button issue, but I would think that a `FragmentTransaction` would be involved somehow.

Comment: @DanielNugent i am facing some problem

Answer (score 0):

1)Store  both of the fragments in public class variables within the main activity.
2)Save the activity within both fragments using the onAttach(activity a) overload.
3)Make a function in both fragments which takes an arrayList.
4)Call the function in the other fragment through the mainactivity you saved from onAttach.