# Pass ArrayList<String> between two activities that extends Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, parameter-passing

I have the activity1 that extends fragment. Here there is an ArrayList (FinalListToSend) that I want to pass to the other activity2

```
 //ACTIVITY1
    public class Page1Activity extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> FinalListToSend;

public ArrayList<String> getList() {
    return FinalListToSend;
}

public void setList(ArrayList<String> FinalListToSend) {
    this.FinalListToSend = FinalListToSend;
}
    public static Page1Activity newInstance() {
    Page1Activity fragment = new Page1Activity();
    return fragment;
    }
public Page1Activity() { }
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page1, container, false);       
   return rootView;
   }
  }
```

I want to get the ArrayList in a second activity2

```
      //ACTIVITY2
     public static Page2Activity newInstance() {
    Page2Activity fragment = new Page2Activity();
    return fragment;
}
public Page2Activity() {    }
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page2, container, false);
     Page1Activity page1= new Page1Activity();
            ArrayList<String> ListToSave = new ArrayList<String>();
            ListToSave=new ArrayList<String>(page1.FinalListToSend);
      return rootView;
     }}
```

I use view pager for this two activities.
I use this code and when I debug the FinalListToSend gets the items correctly when I am in Page1Activity, but when I press the button on PageActivity the FinalListToSend gets null.Any idea to get the array from the second activity?

Comment: are you using view pager

Comment: Yes I have a view pager

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829985/sending-arraylist-between-2-fragments-on-same-activity see this

Comment: use Bundle insted intent..

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it.Needs to set the arraylist in the main activity as Final static

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static ArrayList<String> FinalListToSend=new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<String> getList() {
    return FinalListToSend;
}

public void setList(ArrayList<String> FinalListToSend) {
    this.FinalListToSend = FinalListToSend;
}
```

and then set it from the first fragment

```
        public class Page1Activity extends Fragment {
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        ArrayList<String> listErgasies = new ArrayList<String>();
        listErgasies.add("DATA");
        MainActivity MA= new MainActivity();
            MA.setList(listErgasies);});
          }
```

and get it from the second fragment

```
      public class Page2Activity extends Fragment {
      saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       ArrayList<String> ListToSave = new ArrayList<String>();
       MainActivity MA= new MainActivity();
            ListToSave=new ArrayList<String>(MA.getList());}
         //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),ListToSave.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with `Bundle`

```
Page2Activity tf = new Page2Activity ();
                 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                 bundle.putString("user_id", usersid);
                 tf.setArguments(bundle);
                 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                 ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tf);
                 ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                 ft.addToBackStack(null);
                 ft.commit();
```

To get bundle data

```
usersid = getArguments().getString("user_id");
```

And for Arraylist you can use

```
bundle.putStringArrayList("alist", yourarraylist);
```

Comment: And to get this data from the other activity?

Comment: Is not working.The first code must be in Page1Activity ?

Comment: Maybe something I made is wrong.I don't know.It's not working

Comment: try to Log and see are you able to get in second fragment or not??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99519/discussion-between-lakhan-and-apollon).

Comment: Thank you very much Lakhan and Happy new year

Answer (score 0):

1) pass the arraylist listErgasies 
from activity 1 to activity 2
[How to pass ArrayList<CustomeObject> from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another)

2) show it as a listView again

Comment: you are right but I have fragment activities.I edit the question